# Remove all cells containing 0 and move values to the left

Tags: r

I have a data set That contains a bunch of zero's along with other values,  I need to remove all cells with zero and move the remaining values to the left.

```
 Item  35  45  55 65 75 85 95 100
 1     35   0   0  0  0 85  0   0
 2      0   0  55 65  0  0  0   0
 3      0   0   0  0 75 85  0   0
 4      0  45   0  0  0  0  0 100
 5      0   0   0  0  0 85 95   0
```

And I need an output of

```
 Item  35  45  55 65 75 85 95 100
 1     35  85  
 2     55  65 
 3     75  85  
 4     45  100
 5     85  95
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do:

```
read.table(text=gsub('\\b0\\b','',do.call(paste,df)),fill=T,col.names = names(df))
  Item X35 X45 X55 X65 X75 X85 X95 X100
1    1  35  85  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
2    2  55  65  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
3    3  75  85  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
4    4  45 100  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
5    5  85  95  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the rows with `apply`, specifying `MARGIN = 1`, then concatenate the elements that are not 0 with `NA` padded at the end based on the number of 0's in the row

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) c(x[x!= 0], rep(NA, sum(x == 0)))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Item = 1:5, `35` = c(35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `45` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 45L, 0L), `55` = c(0L, 55L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `65` = c(0L, 
65L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `75` = c(0L, 0L, 75L, 0L, 0L), `85` = c(85L, 
 0L, 85L, 0L, 85L), `95` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 95L), `100` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 100L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
 ))
```